# hard to find runtime error location within react-native

Tags: react-native

[image: a img]

Just as the picture shows. It's really hard to find out where the error located, especially when code base is very large. There is no stack trace associated with your code.

Anyone knows any solution?

Answer (score 1):

[It is recommended](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#content) that you use Chrome's 'Pause on Caught Exceptions' option in order to capture the inner-most error.

Beware though, sometimes what you catch is not really an exception.  But it's the only/best way to get at the thing that actually caused the error at times.